# How to get sound from PDM microphone on Google Coral Dev board ( mini )?

Tags: python, google-coral

I just got my hands on the amazing Google Coral dev board, but I lack enough tutorials or software ecosystem around. I looked into the datasheet and found that there is a PDM microphone on the board. My question is, how can I record sound from it? Is there any native app for that and can I do it from python? Thanks

Comment: You can record the audio via arecord command like : arecord -d 5 -f cd test.wav (Speak something for 5 seconds)
aplay test.wav (You should here in an earphone, what you recorded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it run via pyaudio

```
import pyaudio
import wave

# the file name output you want to record into
filename = "recorded.wav"
# set the chunk size of 1024 samples
chunk = 1024
# sample format
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
# mono, change to 2 if you want stereo
channels = 1
# 44100 samples per second
sample_rate = 44100
record_seconds = 5
# initialize PyAudio object
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# open stream object as input & output
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=channels,
                rate=sample_rate,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk)
frames = []
print("Recording...")
for i in range(int(44100 / chunk * record_seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)
print("Finished recording.")
# stop and close stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# terminate pyaudio object
p.terminate()
# save audio file
# open the file in 'write bytes' mode
wf = wave.open(filename, "wb")
# set the channels
wf.setnchannels(channels)
# set the sample format
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
# set the sample rate
wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
# write the frames as bytes
wf.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
# close the file
wf.close()
```

or as @Manoj stated, one can use arecord native app